# Unable to provision Confluent Cloud Kafka cluster with PrivateLink using ccloud CLI?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

I am trying to provision a **dedicated** Kafka cluster using the `ccloud` CLI (version 1.38.0), but I don't see the option to create a privatelink in the `ccloud kafka create cluster` command:

```
Examples:
Create a new dedicated cluster that uses a customer-managed encryption key in AWS:

      $ ccloud kafka cluster create sales092020 --cloud "aws" --region "us-west-2" --type "dedicated" --cku 1 --encryption-key "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab"
    
    For more information, see https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/clusters/byok-encrypted-clusters.html.
    
    Flags:
          --cloud string            REQUIRED: Cloud provider ID (e.g. 'aws' or 'gcp').
          --region string           REQUIRED: Cloud region ID for cluster (e.g. 'us-west-2').
          --availability string     Availability of the cluster. Allowed Values: single-zone, multi-zone. (default "single-zone")
          --type string             Type of the Kafka cluster. Allowed values: basic, standard, dedicated. (default "basic")
          --cku int                 Number of Confluent Kafka Units (non-negative). Required for Kafka clusters of type 'dedicated'.
          --encryption-key string   Encryption Key ID (e.g. for Amazon Web Services, the Amazon Resource Name of the key).
      -o, --output string           Specify the output format as "human", "json", or "yaml". (default "human")
          --environment string      Environment ID.
          --context string          CLI context name.
```

However, I can see the option to create the private link in the networking section when I try to provision it via the Confluent UI.

Is this feature not supported by the `ccloud` CLI or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Confluent Cloud CLI doesn’t currently support creating PrivateLink clusters.  This is a known limitation and is on the roadmap to fix, but at the moment I believe you’ll have to use the UI for the initial creation of a PrivateLink cluster.